# How do I use jQuery to select all children except a select element

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a div (let's say the id is "container") with many elements in it, including a select element. I'd like to select all everything in the div except the select.
Things I've tried:

```
$("#container *:not(select)")
$("#container *:not(#selectorid)")

//put a div around the select and...
$("#container *:not(#selectorcontainer)")
$("#container *:not(#selectorcontainer *)")
$("#container *:not(#selectorcontainer, #selectorcontainer *)")
```

Also tried without wildcard descendant selector, so just like all the above, but

```
$("#container:not(#selectorid)")
```

Comment: Maybe provide more code (i.e, the html code). When the proper syntax doesn't work... then we have a logical problem here, so more information is probably needed.

Comment: Select isn't broken. ;-)

Comment: Do you mean the selector is also selecting the options within the select? The :not(select) will filter the select but not the options

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can simply omit the wildcard as it is optional in this case, but keep the space:

```
$('#container :not(select)');
```

Alternatively, use the .not() method to filter out the select after selecting all children:

```
$('#container').children().not('select');
```

If your problem is that children of `select` are still included, you could explicitly filter those out with the .not() method:

```
$('#container').children().not('select, option, optgroup');
```

or select direct children only:

```
$('#container > :not(select)');
```

You can try out jQuery selectors at [the interactive jQuery selector tester](http://www.woods.iki.fi/interactive-jquery-tester.html) for quick feedback; try for example `div :not(ol)` or `div > :not(ol)` to get a feel for what difference the direct child (`>`) selector makes.

Comment: Great tip about the interactive tester! I got a couple of things to work: $("#featured > :not('select')") and $("#featured").children().not("select") buy very strangely not $("#featured").children().not("#selectorId") and not $("#featured > :not('#selectorID')")

Comment: Omit the quotes. Just use :not(seletor), so :not(#selectorID) and it'll work fine.

Comment: regarding you guys comments above: that one reason why I'd prefer using `$('#container').children().not('select');`, less error prone ;)

Answer (score 4):

#### Using `:not`, and `.not()` to select and filter » [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bpfU5/1/)

The [`:not(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) does exactly this, and it comes in a couple styles. You can use the *selector*, or the *method*. Below is an example of using the selector:

```
$("#container :not(select)");
```

This will match any child within `#container` that is *not* a `<select>` element. Then we have the method fashion of exclusion, which goes by the same name, but must be ran differently:

```
$("#container").children().not("select");
```

This runs against the `children` of the matched elements. In this case, `.not` acts as a filter. Which brings me to the next example, using [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get the results you want. With this method, we can provide our own custom function to rummage through the results and pick the ones we want:

#### Using `.filter()` to filter the matched elements » [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bpfU5/)

```
$( "#container" ).children().filter( isNotSELECT ).fadeTo( "slow", .5 );​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

function isNotSELECT () {
    // Returns TRUE if element is NOT select
    return !$(this).is("select");
}
```

In this example, we select all of the children of `#container`, and then pass them through a filter that we have defined called "isNotSelect". Within our filter, we return either `true` or `false` for every element. If we return `true`, that element will be returned to the result set. If we return `false`, that element will be removed from the result set. We're asking if the element is *not* a select. This will return `false` for all select elements, thus removing them from our collection.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try it using traversing methods:

```
$('#container').children().not('#selectorId');
```

or being a final option:

```
$('#container').children().filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('id') !== 'selectorId';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the traversing method.
I got it to work by $("#featured").children().not("select") 
Also I found it very strange that $("#featured").children().not("#selectorId") does not work in this case.

Comment: id searches may be case-sensitive (not sure).

You can always use the form attributes. Form elements usually have names, so you could use: "select[name=selectname]". But getting via id is always faster.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(#container select).siblings()
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/siblings

Answer (score 1):

[JQuery click handler for everything but a certain object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109835/quick-html-jquery-question)
Two approaches to the problem: The one with [8 votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109835/quick-html-jquery-question/1109851#1109851) is probably the one you are looking for.

Comment: You have the latest version of JQuery? (1.3 and above)

Comment: Just tried with 1.3. Different behavior, still not correct, but select element stays if I use #3 (from above) and other children are doing wierd things, though.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you actually want from your question.
:not(select) will filter out the select from all the descendants but it will not out the select descendants. If this is your issue then try the following

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ateqe)

```
$("#container *").filter( function(){ 
    return $(this).closest('select').length === 0 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this can help you 
where 3 is the #select

try one of these:

```
$("#container *:not(eq(3))");
$("#container").children().filter(:not(eq(3)));
```