# jquery selecting whole body besides one div

Tags: jquery, toggle

I would like to select whole body besides one div. Or maybe someone has better idea how to accomplish my problem.

I want to on  "cs-dropdown" click toggle, and then if someone clicks out of it anywhere in the body hide it. The problem is that "cs-dropdown" is inside the body right after I open it with "cs-dropdown" click I am closing it with body click. Thanks for any help.

```
$(".cs-dropdown").click(function () {
        $(".customer-service-dd").toggle();
});


$("body").click(function () {

    if($(".customer-service-dd").is(":visible") == true)
    {
    $(".customer-service-dd").toggle();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)** to stop the event from bubbling to the body:

```
$(".cs-dropdown").click(function (ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
    $(".customer-service-dd").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

[How do I use jQuery to select all children except a select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125700/how-do-i-use-jquery-to-select-all-children-except-a-select-element)

```
$('body').not('#theItemYouDontWant');
```

I'm just guessing =)

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$("body").click(function () {

    if($(".customer-service-dd").is(":visible") == true)
    {
    $(".customer-service-dd").toggle();
    }

});
```

To:

```
$("body").live('click', function () {

    if($(".customer-service-dd").is(":visible") == true)
    {
    $(".customer-service-dd").toggle();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your click on the dropdown is propagating up to the body so that both click handlers are called.  You can prevent events from propagating by using `e.stopPropagation()`.  That way handlers for the same event on parent elements are not called.  Add `e.stopPropagation()` inside the `.cs-dropdown` click handler:

```
$(".cs-dropdown").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".customer-service-dd").toggle();
});
```