# remove children of particular parent from selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the structure of my html

```
<div class="parent">
//many other elements
<div class="child">
<div class="grandchild"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

I want to select all elements inside parent except elements inside child

I tried the below one which didnt work

```
$(".parent *:not(.child *)")
```

How can I select that?

Comment: `$('.parent *')` is this tried already?

Comment: Check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125700/how-do-i-use-jquery-to-select-all-children-except-a-select-element

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.parent *').filter(function(){
      return $(this).parents('.child').length === 0;
});
```

This will select all elements inside `.parent` except those who are also children / sub-children of `.child`

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.parent *:not(.child, .child *)')
```

Try this.

Although maybe you want this:

```
$(".parent > *:not(.child)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
will select all the div that start with the class child under the parent class **.parent**.

```
$('.parent div[class^="child"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.parent *').not('.child *')
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to select all elements inside parent except elements inside
>   child

you can use find method.
It will find all the descendants/children  except children inside class `child`

```
$(".parent").find("*").not($(".child").children()).each(function(){
alert($(this).prop("class"));
});
```