# Why does the div move down before sliding when I try to hide it with jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#test").hide("slide", {
      direction: "left"
    }, 2000)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1>
    base base base
  </h1>
  <div id="test">
    <h3>
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    </h3>
    <button>test</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get rid of this small movement down? ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x48nzqLt))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find `h3` inside `div` and hide that one instead of the `#test`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#test").find('h3').hide("slide", {
      direction: "left"
    }, 2000)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1>
    base base base
  </h1>
  <div id="test">
    <h3>
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    </h3>
    <button>test</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Working JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ur1wy8m9/)

Comment: Thank you! worked. Out of curiosity, Is it documented somewhere? I searched online for 3 hours and couldn't find any solution.

Comment: No. I face same problem previously and  know slide only work with main container , using parent container  gives weird problem :).

Comment: I have a follow up question. what can I do if I have many elements in the div, not just h3, and I want to animate the entire div?

Comment: @GEV select all their children with `$("#test").children()`. You will need to put the `button` outside `#test`, though, or use [`.children().not(...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1126074) method.